# Numpy Indexing: Get every second coloumn for each even row

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I want to select in an numpy array all odd off diagonals. Basically the following:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
b = a[::2,1::2] and at the same time a[1::2,::2]
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 4, 6],
       [9, 11],
       [12,14]])
```

To formulate it differently: In each even row I want to have each second column with an offset of one and in each odd row I want to have each second column. It would be great if that could be achieved without creating an additional copy.

Comment: Just a note: it isn't possible to get a view of this subarray (and avoid a copy) because the stride lengths are not constant in each dimension. For example, moving down axis 0, sometimes you jump three values (e.g. 1 to 4), sometimes four values (e.g. 4 to 8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay if we can not avoid any copy, than the easiest thing to do would be probably something like:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]/2))
b[::2,:]  = a[::2,1::2]
b[1::2,:] = a[1::2,::2]
>>>> b
array([[  1.,   3.],
   [  4.,   6.],
   [  9.,  11.],
   [ 12.,  14.]])
```